# Reset position of object before setLinearVelocity

Tags: android, andengine

I'm playing around with AndEngine and its physic extension

And I can't use the setPosition properly.

I'm trying to reset the position of my object on each new user action : A touch Down, should throw the object again from its original position

What I'm doing is :

```
public void throwObject(){
    objectSprite.setPosition(xScene, yScene);
    objectBody.setLinearVelcity(touchXWorld, touchYWorld);
}
```

Note that I'm using scene coordinates for `setPosition` but I'm not sure what I should use here...

`setLinearVelocity` is working fine but the object is thrown from its current position. The `setPosition()` call did nothing.

Any clue on how to use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `setPosition` on your Sprite. Your body stays at the same position. When the body updates it's position the sprite follows it.

To move the body you can use the method `setTransform`. It takes two arguments, a `Vector2` object with the new position and a float - the new rotation angle.

Comment: Yank you! For futur readers, there is more details about it on this thread http://www.andengine.org/forums/physics-box2d-extension/set-position-of-dynamic-body-t7441.html